# Determine class of every input argument in R function

Tags: r, function

Consider having a function, that accepts any number of arguments:

```
FUN <- function(...) { 
   #/some code/
   }
```

How to determine the **classes of input arguments** to this function `FUN`**?**

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars)
char <- "lalala"
DF <- data.frame(ch)
f <- function(x) x*x

FUN(g, char, DF, "DF", list(), f, `%in%`, NULL, TRUE, "TRUE")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this:

```
FUN <- function(...) {
  elipsis <- list(...)
  print(sapply(elipsis, class))
  ##/some code/
  }
```

However, you must make sure you are passing in sensible thing. For example:

```
FUN("lalala", trees, "DF", list(), function(x) x * x, `%in%`, NULL, TRUE, "TRUE")
# [1] "character"  "data.frame" "character"  "list"       "function"  
# [6] "function"   "NULL"       "logical"    "character"
```